Next.js scrolling filters together with scrolling products
I am working in next js , and i want to implement endless scrolling and I have a sidebar on the left side of my page, with filters, and I want to make this filters bar scrolling with the products, but when filters bar scrolled to it end/start, i want it to stop (but products should be keep scrolling).
Here is example of what behavior I want:
https://green-dostavka.by/catalog/
Maybe there is a guide for that or smth like that, can't find solution
